# Expect In Bash Script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, automation, expect

I am trying to write an autobuild script. Towards the end of the build command the user is prompted for a password, I'd like to automatically senter the password.  What I have at the moment is

```
#!/bin/bash

##stored username and password
userName = [username]
password = [password]

##connect to build server
ssh ${username]@xx.x.xx.xx

##checkout copy from svn
svn co [path of code]

##change directory to build directory
cd [build directory of checked out code]

##start build 
##expect password
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
    expect "Password: "
    spawn make build
    send ${password}
EOF

exit
echo "Build Complete"
```

Another way I was shown of doing the expect within a bash script

```
expect -c \
    "set timeout -1; \
    spawn make build; \
    expect \"password: \"; \
    send -- \[password]\r\"; \
    expect eof"
```

in the second example the [password] is actuallay a string of the password required.

It sticks on when the build command prompts for password.  I have tried a few other examples and spawn seems to not work at all e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
expect "hello"
spawn echo "hello"
send "world"
```

that does nothing until I type "hello"

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated, but are you expecting the `svn` and what follows to execute *on* the build server? It won't; those commands won't execute until you log out of the shell started by the `ssh` command.

Comment: Which command, exactly, is prompting for a password? Your two scripts show the expected prompt occurring before and after, respectively, the `make build` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chepner  commented, your logic is wrong: you're doing most of the work on your local machine, not remotely.  You need something like this to connect to the remote server and interact with the login shell there:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

##stored username and password
set userName "username"
set password "password"
set prompt "pattern to match user's prompt"

##connect to build server
spawn ssh $username@xx.x.xx.xx
expect -re $prompt

##checkout copy from svn
send "svn co [path of code]\r"
expect -re $prompt

##change directory to build directory
send "cd [build directory of checked out code]\r"
expect -re $prompt

##start build 
set timeout -1           ; # wait as long as required for build to finish
send "make build\r"
expect "Password: "
send -- "$password\r"

# get a prompt when build complete
expect -re $prompt
send "exit\r"
expect eof

puts "Build Complete"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll give this a go tomorrow morning :)